# Build failed with an exceptio (:app:validateSigningDebug)

Tags: android, flutter

i use visual studio code for firs time and i run flutter aplecation and then i got this error please help me

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile$ActionExecutionException: java.io.IOException: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to create keystore.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading through the documentation on how to sign an Android app, which can be found here https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#debug-mode

You will need to generate a debug keystore using the command

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

(of course changing the passwords to something you will remember)

and place it in either

- ~/.android/ (on Mac or Linux)
- C:\Users\user.android\ (on Windows)

Another good source of information is here https://coderwall.com/p/r09hoq/android-generate-release-debug-keystores